# Understanding structure for app with ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I need help with understanding structure for my "small student management app". I need to:

1. Create SUBJECT.
2. Subject has a name and number of categories which are types of grades eg. Java, 2, Homework, Project
3. Each type of grade has weight e.g. Homework, 10
4. Save that in file
5. Input grades for STUDENT for selected SUBJECT
6. Student has ID, name, and grades for each of categories that SUBJECT was chosen.
7. Save to file
8. Do some calculations with weight from SUBJECT and inserted grades for student.

I have wrote two methods:

```
private void createSubject(String name, 
                           int numberOfCat, 
                           List<String> category, 
                           List<Integer> weight);

private void insertGrade(int id, String name, List<Integer> grade);
```

These methods save input to subjects.txt and students.txt as my database tables. I have also methods for editGrade and deleteSubject as well as viewGrades and viewSubjects

Right now I can add to my filines like that e.g.:

subjects.txt -> (Java, Homework, 10, Project, 40, Final,50,)

students.txt -> (001, John)

My problems start here. I can't imagine right now how can I:

1. Select one SUBJECT from subjects.txt
2. Insert grades for student. Number of grades must match number of categories in selected SUBJECT.(Thats why in insertGrade I have saved only ID and name)
3. Retrieve weights so I can do calculations with grades inserted by user.

If anyone can help me with understanding how can I make it. I don't need a code but I would love to get some clarification how to look at it. Thank you and I'm ready to talk and learn ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to abstract **Subject** and **Student** into classes?

```
public class Execute {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //1.Creating some instance of Grade
        Grade grade1 = new Grade("Homework", 10);
        Grade grade2 = new Grade("Project,", 40);
        Grade grade3 = new Grade("Final,", 50);

        //2.Putting all these grades in an ArrayList
        List<Grade> grades = new ArrayList<Grade>();
        grades.add(grade1);
        grades.add(grade2);
        grades.add(grade3);

        //3.Creating an instance of Subject
        Subject Java = new Subject("Java", grades);

        //4.Putting the subject in an ArrayList
        List<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<Subject>();
        subjects.add(Java);

        //5.Creating an instance of Student
        Student student = new Student("001", "John", subjects);

        /**
         * Now you have a student called John, choosing a subject called Java.
         * There are 3 parts of this course: Homework, Project, and Final exam.
         */
    }
}

public class Student {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<Subject> subjects;

    public Student(String id, String name, List<Subject> subjects) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }
}

public class Grade {
    private String name;
    private Integer weight;

    public Grade(String name, Integer weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}

public class Subject {

    private String name;
    private List<Grade> grades;

    public Subject(String name, List<Grade> grades) {
        this.name = name;
        this.grades = grades;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I will have to test it in the morning with Scanner. Thanks for some ideas, I'll update how it went.

Comment: :) Ok, let me know if you need any help.@Alp3n

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand you correctly, you do work on the text files. I would not do that.

Load both files on startup and get their content into corresponding classes like students and subjects.

Now with all data loaded, you can easily work on them (like iterate over you lists and so on). At the end, replace the files with the new content.

For the subjects, maybe a map would be nice, if it is really just the two information.

Is it helping you or did I get you wrong?

Comment: He listed his task's conditions, which state to save the info in file. However it is indeed really better to store information in memory of a program

Comment: Sorry, my answer wasn't clear. It's totally fine to work on files (though I would prefer yaml but anyhow).

Even so you store the information in these files, does not mean that you have to work on the files instead of the loaded information.

Comment: To be honest in my app I have only methods that write to /read from those text files. You propose me to build classes, methods for classes and work on that and add option to print whole memory to the file? I was thinking about those files to be similar to "SQL tables". I didn't want to use SQL in this because I want to learn to work on Lists<>